# Rotate Arrow 180 degree android

Tags: android

## how can i rotate image with 180 degree like ::

[image]

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
            int w = oldBitmap.getWidth();
    int h = oldBitmap.getHeight();
    String filePath = null;
    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();

    mtx.postRotate(180);

    oldBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(oldBitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
```

Cheers!!!